# SQL Query return twice value

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Hello everyone it's my first  post on Stackoverflow :)

My problem might be simple for you guys but I can´t figure out what is wrong...

```
SELECT *
FROM ecrit INNER JOIN
     friends f
     ON f.idfriend = ecrit.idAuteurPost  
WHERE ecrit.idAuteurPost = 2 OR f.isvalidate = 1
ORDER BY dateEcrit DESC
```

It return me this :

[image]

What I want is the same result just not returned twice. I've tried using `DISCTINCT` and `GROUP BY` but with no success. Thanks you for your time and patience.
See ya.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.

Comment: What columns do you need in your result?

Comment: You get the rows twice because of the `iduser` column. Try to exclude this column and see if it works like you want it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bit long for a comment.

I see no duplicated results in your result set.  There are pairs of results where `id_user` differs between them.  It is unclear what you want, but perhaps `exists` is:

```
SELECT e.*
FROM ecrit e
WHERE e.idAuteurPost = 2 OR
      EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM friends f
              WHERE f.idfriend = e.idAuteurPost AND  
                    f.isvalidate = 1
             )
ORDER BY e.dateEcrit DESC;
```

Comment: Thanks you !! that's exactly what i was looking for, i didnt thought about exists

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you're results are not really duplicated, since iduser is different, so, if you're not using iduser, specify in your query the fields that you DO use, and leave iduser out, I think that'll do, like so:

```
SELECT ecrit.dateEcrit, friends.isValidate, ... FROM
...
```